# How will Google Native Client change the way we use Browsers?

Tags: browser, google-nativeclient

I just came across [Google Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)

Now, it looks really interesting that they ported **Quake to run on a Browser** and you can run C++ code on a browser to process things more quickly, but I am trying to understand, what is the practical usage of NaCl?

**What is the vision behind this by Google?** To run software as a service on their "cloud" OS..err browser?

For example: Run Photosphop CS 5 on your browser?!

Comment: I really don't think "Google" is as unified as the name makes it sound.  It's a bunch of engineers doing projects they think are cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do with ActiveX, but far more secure.

---

***Elaboration:***

Google Native Client allows you to run machine code locally and natively, but sandboxed insofar as only allowing access to protected memory regions and disabling exploits in the machine code relating to processor errata (certain sequences of machine code operations which act strangely on particular processors). Additionally, certain APIs are available (such as OpenGL) and there is interprocess communication with Javascript running with the page, allowing webapps which have a fast, powerful native backend.

It would be quite difficult to use the Win32 API to generate any native windows or controls with Google Native Client, whereas it'd be probably a bit easier with ActiveX. However, ActiveX is generally used with things like "Quake Live" to provide a fast, native experience for the player, and additionally for Internet Explorer 'plug-ins' -- the Flash plug-in is ActiveX, for instance, and uses native code (i.e., the plugin is compiled to machine code).

Comment: You can please elaborate your answer.

Comment: "the Flash plug-in is ActiveX" - really? I always assumed that IE also used Netscape type plugins.

Comment: Yep, it's ActiveX. Wikipedia even says: "ActiveX controls are used for content handlers that render content embedded within an HTML page (e.g., Adobe Flash or Microsoft Silverlight)."

I've had to do development with the ActiveX plug-in in the past, which first required me to first install the Internet Explorer plug-in.